# I have a Canon MF741Cdw Color Imageclass. I had it running remotely at my last address. Now I think I need a reset. How do I accomplish that?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, printer, reset

I have Windows 10. This all ran remotely at my last address. But now that I have moved to another state, I cannot figure out how to get it to communicate with my computer via wifi. When I work through the menu and find numbers, none of them match my numbers not even the printer IP. Everything I find on line is for other models that have different command buttons or a a stop button. I have none of those.

Comment: We need much more details about your computer and router. Screenshots of the problems will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks a lot of detail, for example which "numbers" do you mean? IP addresses? Which menu do you use? Is this in a large organisation? They may have specific requirements for IP addressing.

I will assume this is happening because at the new location the IP address range used is different from the old location. And I will assume that you are allowed to set the printer's IP address yourself. If you do work for an organisation, ask your IT people for help with the settings. Finally I will assume you use a PC, not a Mac.

Here's how to give the printer an IP address.

First check the IP address of the PC. You can do that by typing IPCONFIG at a DOS prompt. Then give the printer one where the first 3 numbers are the same as the PC, but the 4th is different. For example, if the PC's address is 192.168.43.101, try an address like 192.168.43.201 for the printer. Try to use a number between 200 and 250.

Now you need to tell the printer to use that address. From the [printer's User Guide](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300034338/03/MF740_640Series_UsersGuide_usEN_1.pdf):

1. Select  on the printer's home screen
2. Select
3. Select <TCP/IP Settings>
4. Select , and select  in
5. Select
6. Enter the IP address as discussed above. For the Subnet Mask and Gateway, use the same settings as the PC.
7. Select
8. Restart the printer

If that does not do the trick, please answer the questions and assumptions above.